# Eloquent ORM how to avoid duplicate conditions

Tags: laravel, scope, eloquent, conditional-statements, relationship

I have two Models: Task and Category (one task belongs to one category but one category has many tasks)

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

    public function scopeCategoryType($query, $cat_type) {
        $query->whereHas('category', function($q) use($cat_type) {
            $q->where('type', $cat_type);
        }
    } 
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function tasks() {
        return $this->hasMany('Task');
    }

    public function scopeType($query, $cat_type) {
        $query->where('type', $cat_type);
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how many tasks in the "Urgent" category and the query below works:

```
$task = new Task();
$res = $task->categoryType('urgent')->count();
```

But as you can see, when i want to select a category with the "Urgent" type, i must create another scope in the Category Model.

```
$cat = new Category();
$res_cat = $cat->type("Normal");
```

So i've writed two times the code to filter a type of categories.

How can i do to optimise my code ?

What i want to show how many "urgent" tasks seems like that:

```
$task->category()->type('urgent')->count();
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel `whereHas` clause with a subquery function like this

```
$data = Task::whereHas('category', function($q) {
    $q -> select(DB::raw(1))
       -> from('categories')
       -> where('cat_type', $cat_type);
    }) ;
 // get the count  
 $count = $data -> count();
// get tasks 
 $taks  =$data -> get();
```

Comment: Thank you, but could i use scope to get my query clearer ?

Comment: Make it a dynamic query scope and count or get as needed.